Will Google Transfer for Education Save my Container-bound Apps Script Files?
I am a teacher and am leaving my school district soon. I have created a large number of container-bound scripts in Google Sheets, Docs and Slides files. I want to take these with me, but when I tried downloading the container file and then uploading it again to Google Drive, I noticed that the scripts were gone. I'm assuming this loss occurs when the file is converted to MS Office format for download.
Another option I have available as a Google Education user is Google Transfer, which appears to simply make a copy of all files in My Drive and place them in the destination account's Drive. Can anyone confirm whether or not my container-bound scripts will still be there if I use this option? (Note that Transfer is different from Takeout, and apparently only available to education accounts)

Yes. The documents will still include their scripts.
Container-bound scripts cannot be detached from the file they are bound to so making a copy of the container document means copying the script as well.
The Transfer tool for Google Workspace for Education is effectively a batch Google Drive copy tool for student and staff accounts to facilitate a process that comes up regularly for schools.
Resources:

Let graduating students transfer data
Copy content from your school account to another account

